# Save Over The XML File I Am Reading

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

How can I read the XML file and edit and save the same file ? Issue I get is 'file is in use' obviously because I'm reading it.. Do I not read it or read it another way ?

Basic idea of what I'm doing is, reading a SQL DB getting the new value written there,
then updating the XML file when the new change.

The `XmlTextWriter` option doesn't seem the write option and its to write a new XML file ?

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(@"C:\Users\Pavle\Desktop\Settings.xml");
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(reader);
doc.SelectSingleNode("/config/Settings/SleepNumber").InnerText = "new2 text";
doc.Save(@"C:\Users\Pavle\Desktop\Settings.xml");
```

Comment: While there are ways to fix this, I'd suggest to actually first write to an intermediate / temporary file, then verify the changes made are correct, then delete original and move/rename new file. In case of a verification fail, you always still have the original, then. (That's the experience from years of dealing with file manipulation: 1. _backup_ 2. don't mess with original 3. read, modify, write to temp, verify, swap )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you need to close the reader before you can write the file.

I have two suggestions for you.

First, try using new LINQ-to-Xml library instead.

Then you could do this:

```
string filename = @"C:\Users\Pavle\Desktop\Settings.xml";
XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Load(filename);
doc2.Root.Element("Settings").Element("SleepNumber").Value = "new2 text";
doc2.Save(filename);
```

Second, it's typical to write a new file, delete the old, and then rename the new back to the old to always make sure you have a valid file at all times on disk. In your code if the write fails you've destroyed your original file. That's a bad idea.

Comment: This works great I saved it twice. Once before update with "file.backup" and once after the changes, thank you! ..... the problem I might face now, .NET 3.0 doesn't have Linq and I need to run this program on old servers with .NET 3.0 and upgrading\installing new framework isn't an option.. so maybe 2 exe's 1 for new and one for old....

Comment: @PavleStojanovic - You don't need LINQ to make this work. Just use the old XML library in the same way as this example.

Comment: So my program reads the XML file to get the login info for the SQL server, then reads the SQL table, then if SQL info and XML info are different to back first and update the XML file with SQL data..

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`Load(string filename)` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.load?view=net-5.0#System_Xml_XmlDocument_Load_System_String_) which takes a file name as parameter instead of a text reader if you read from files on disk.

If that's not possible, use the approach described by Mark Russinovich in the Windows Internals book *): Safe Saving. It says:

1. Save to a temporary new file
2. Close the original file
3. Delete the original file
4. Rename the temporary file to the original file name

If you do that, the NTFS file system driver will notice the operation and keep the relevant parts of the original MAC timestamps of the file. MAC is short for modified, accessed, created.

This approach also avoids data loss in case of power failure or other severe events: the original file will be available as long as possible.

*) e.g. Windows Internals 6, part 2, chapter 12 ("File systems"), subchapter "Tunneling", page 452 in the first printing

Answer (score 1):

You can try closing XmlTextReader before saving. XmlTextReader locks the file until it is closed.

Comment: I thought of this, but couldn't find the Close or Exit option..